# Database solution for route matching

Tags: database, gis, geospatial

i'm working on an application that lets users search for trips from point A to point B.
it needs to solve the following use cases:

1. find trips that go from point A to point B
2. find trips that start in some other point, but go trough point A to point B

I'm now looking for a database solution that would be best to support such use cases.

For now we are using MongoDB. But i had to figure out a workaround for the first use case and i have a feling that it's not possible to solve the second use case with it.

It seems to me that all the available noSql dbs that support spatial features allow only for one geospatial index on a document,node etc. This is fine for queries like show me all shops in radius of 5km from this point and the like.

So i'm looking for a solution that could solve both use cases. Is there something like that available?

Comment: "find trips that start in some other point, but go trough point A to point B" - you have to make two routing queries, from some other point to A and from A to B, or am I missing something?

Comment: maybe i haven't explained clearly enough. we have a list of routes from point A to point B. now a user wants to go from point C to point B. point C lies on the route bewtween A to B. now he searches for a trip from C to B, the system should also return the trip from A to B, as it passes through C.

Comment: I think you need to define clearly what a 'trip' is, and what a 'route' is, and whether these are the same..

Comment: Sorry, still don't get it. What is "route from A to B"? Coordinates for two points? List of all edges, that form route from A to B?

Comment: well, we're build a car sharing app. User A posts an offer that he goes from New York to Columbus. User B wants to go from Pittsburgh to Columbus. So he enters on the search page from: Pittsburgh, to: Ohio. User B travels through Pittsburgh. So the search results for user B's search should also show the route that user A has saved into our system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pgRouting could be used, indeed. First solution, that pops into mind: when first user has entered New York and Columbus as source and destination of his trip, perform routing query and store path as PostGIS linestring geometry.

When second user enters From: Pittsburgh To: Columbus into search form, geocode city names to locations and make PostGIS queries, how far are those points (or city boundaries) from first user's route path. If they are close enough and first user drives on suitable direction, they could share car.

Second idea: after first user has entered trip details, perform routing query and store all place names, that are passed by route, into database.

Both solutions could be easily implemented with Postgres+PostGIS+pgRouting. Biggest disadvantage of pgRouting is low speed (it's possible to improve performance by reducing data in routing graph; routing speed is not so important etc). It's also possible to export road data to external files; use some high-speed routing engines (like OSRM, MoNav etc); and, if necessary, write result back to PostGIS. But this requires definitely much more effort.

Comment: That's the way to do it - I'd go with the first approach. You could even give User B a list of trips being made in order of distance from his or her start point, since he or she might be able to get somewhere close.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you choose to avoid the Database route (no pun intended), you could use `GeoTools` graphing Java library.

http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/extension/graph/index.html

Here is some example code and data I produced myself to demonstrate how it can be used.

http://usefulpracticalgeoblog.blogspot.ch/2012/09/geotools-routing.html

It is pretty flexible in terms of the spatial data formats that can be used to build the street network graph, and how the results can be outputted.

Then to find if the starting point of trip B is close to the pre-calculated route for Trip A, you could use `JTS (Java Topology Suite)`, which is part of the GeoTools library. Here is an example of the analysis you might use.

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7699/for-a-given-feature-find-the-closest-point-along-a-given-path

Answer (score 0):

Postgresql with postgis and pgrouting. You need nothing else.

Comment: Can you provide an example how to match two routes with different starting points?

Comment: I've misunderstood your question. pgrouting will find routes given a network of roads and some points. You have a database of routes, and want to query it, right? It would have been helpful to see your database schema...

Comment: there is no schema yet, as we are looking for the best solution to support our use cases. see my comment above for further clarification